# Initializing specific members in C

Tags: pointers, struct

i want to define struct

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
//#include "templog.h"
#define DATE_SIZE      5
 typedef struct {
    int id;
    int year;
    int month;
    int mday;
    float min_temp, max_temp;
    } tempValue_t
```

and the data is

```
tempValue_t temps[DATE_SIZE] =
    { 0, { .tm_year = 2015, .tm_mon = 0, .tm_mday = 1 }, 19.26, 20.76 },
```

and i receive the message

```
error field name not in record or union initializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that the structure members can be initialized even nested structures can be initialized with (.).